# Passing variable to PHP with AJAX doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass an integer to php code where it would then store it to WAMP sql db, however I can't get this to work.

JS function - item is the integer I want to store:

```
function storeData(item){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'var1': item
        },
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(results){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost:3306";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $databaseName = "items";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $databaseName);
    //$dbs = mysqli_select_db($databaseName, $con);

    $itemNumber = $_POST['var1'];

    echo json_encode($itemNumber);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO item_list (item_number) VALUES ('$itemNumber')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
?>
```

I just get this error - XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: file:///C:/wamp64/www/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/insert.php
Line Number 8, Column 3:

Comment: still nothing, it doesn't even echo back the value into console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, apparently I needed to specify full path for URL, didn't think it was required as both, main file and php file were in the same folder.

```
function storeData(item){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/main.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'var1': item
        },
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(results){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just querying the database is not enough. You then have to send something back to the javascript. A status message would be enough in this case

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost:3306";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $databaseName = "items";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $databaseName);
    //$dbs = mysqli_select_db($databaseName, $con);

    $itemNumber = $_POST['var1'];

    echo json_encode($itemNumber);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO item_list (item_number) VALUES ('$itemNumber')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if (!$result) {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'FAILED'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK'));
    }
?>
```

And in your js code

```
function storeData(item){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'var1': item },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("In success method");
            console.log("status returned " + data.status);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the console.log to work u need a success method, so change it from:

```
function storeData(item){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        var1: item
      }
    });}
```

To:

```
function storeData(item){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        var1: item
      },
      success: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
      }
    });}
```

Also for better reading I recommend u to json_encode your data:

```
echo json_encode($itemNumber);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I applied above changes, however I'm still not getting back anything in console.

Comment: @user1796741 Can u try to comment `$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);` those out and try it again? Also which state are u getting a 500?

Comment: yap, just did, still no luck :/

Comment: How does your document root like? Is insert.php somewhere else or in the same directory as index.php? Try to add a slash before insert.php like: /insert.php

Comment: I updated my code in a question, I always get console.log("error") triggered, when I add  /insert.php it gets rid of XML error message, but still triggers console.log("error")